# How to install Nova Breadcrumbs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

[Breadcrumbs](https://github.com/chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs) is a tool that adds a clickable path to nova resources to help with navigation. Unfortunately, after I follow the steps in the installation manual like so:

**`app/Providers/NovaServiceProdivder.php`**:

```
use Laravel\Nova\NovaApplicationServiceProvider;

class NovaServiceProvider extends NovaApplicationServiceProvider
    
    ...

    public function tools()
{
    return [
        \ChrisWare\NovaBreadcrumbs\NovaBreadcrumbs::make(),
    ];
}
```

**`app/Nova/Resource.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Laravel\Nova\Resource as NovaResource;
use ChrisWare\NovaBreadcrumbs\Traits\Breadcrumbs;

abstract class Resource extends NovaResource
{
    use Breadcrumbs;
    ....
}
```

the path tool does not appear and my browser shows:

```
:3000/nova-vendor/chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js?id=e2c07eb6c9b9faf610fc:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at FtD3.t.exports (vendor.js:1)
    at t.exports (vendor.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y (vendor.js:1)
:3000/nova-vendor/chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js?id=e2c07eb6c9b9faf610fc:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at FtD3.t.exports (vendor.js?id=e2c07eb6c9b9faf610fc:1)
    at t.exports (vendor.js?id=e2c07eb6c9b9faf610fc:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y (vendor.js?id=e2c07eb6c9b9faf610fc:1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***I have installed and configured it this way.
It's a little different from the official doc.
I hope it can help you! :)***

---

**STEP 1**

```
composer require chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs
```

---

**STEP 2**

```
use ChrisWare\NovaBreadcrumbs\Traits\Breadcrumbs;

abstract class Resource extends NovaResource
{
    use Breadcrumbs;
    /* CODE */
}
```

---

**STEP 3**

File: *"NOVA_FOLDER/src/NovaServiceProvider.php"*

```
use ChrisWare\NovaBreadcrumbs\NovaBreadcrumbs;

/* CODE */

public function registerRoutes()
{
    return [
        new NovaBreadcrumbs,
    ];
}
```

**Works like a charm!**

[Link to package](https://github.com/chris-ware/nova-breadcrumbs)